# no data found when there is data

Tags: oracle11g, sqlplus

I came across this weird scenario and I do not know what I am doing wrong:

To simplify the issue, I have a table called ABC with the following structure:

```
MyValue varchar2(10)
MyKey  Number
```

And this is my data set in table ABC

```
null, 1
null, 2
null, 3
'WYZ', 4
```

I have a function:

```
function DEF
RETURN varchar2
is
v varchar2(10);
Begin
  SELECT "MyValue" INTO v
  WHERE "MyKey"<5 and "MyValue" is not null;
  RETURN v;
End;
```

When I tested outside the program, the query yielded result 'WYZ' but when I tested the function, it encountered an no data found error!
Can someone tell me what I have done incorrectly?

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible test case (DDL to create the table, DML to populate the data, and the code that throws the error)?  What you're saying doesn't make sense so something in your description must be off.  Either the data in the table is not what you posted (potentially because you have uncommitted changes in one session that are not visible in another) or the code that you're posting isn't what is actually throwing the error.

Comment: Or the function is seeing a table with the same name in a different schema, maybe? Are you doing everything in one schema?

Comment: @JustinCave: Justin, you could be correct. It is a complex database with multiple tables, views and relations, so it would not be feasible to provide you with a reproducible test case. But it could very well be that the error I saw was actually not the code I suspected as you pointed out. You have helped me narrowing down the problematic area and simplify my troubleshooting process since you have confirmed that the code above is correct. I will verify other block inside the sp and also check for uncommitted changes.

Comment: @AlexPoole: Thanks for looking into it. Everything is in only one schema but a very complex one. Justin could be right, the error could be caused by another block and not this one.